# Preventing login requests using OAuth2 with the same user but multiple devices

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We're using Grails and the OAuth2 plugin, but this is a more general OAuth2 question.

We're trying to work out an issue where the same user is using multiple devices and we don't want to prompt for their user/password if it's not necessary. Take the following for example:

- AT = Access Token
- RT = Refresh Token

(Assume initial ATs can be obtained using the password grant type and both devices get the same AT)

```
Device 1:
1. Refresh, new AT
5. Bad AT
6. Refresh denied (bad RT)
7. Need Password for AT, new RT ... Repeats every time it expires

Device 2:
2. Bad AT 
3. Refresh denied (bad RT)
4. Need Password for new AT/RT
```

We obviously don't want to cache the password, and shouldn't need to prompt the user when we have a refresh token.  There is a flag to reuse the refresh token, but if we did, we'd end up generating new access tokens, for example:

```
Device 1:
1. Refresh, new AT
4. Bad AT
5. Refresh, new AT… Repeats every request

Device 2:
2. Bad AT
3. Refresh, new AT
```

I assume we're not the first to encounter this type of problem, so I thought I'd reach out for thoughts/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your 2 devices need to be getting different access tokens and refresh tokens. The number of distinct tokens granted depends on the `TokenStore` implementation, so that's where you should concentrate probably. Maybe you can use a custom `AuthenticationKeyGenerator` to ensure that that 2 devices get different tokens? Or use JWT?